# Js - Unable to print/get the correct values of dynamically selected drop down

Tags: javascript, html

Code is in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgd21qr3/).

There are 4 drop-down input types (Year, Make, Model, and Parts).
Year, Make and Parts are independent. But the model is loaded based on what the make is.
When I try to print the values in the text box, it does not show the model correctly. Can you please help me how to fix this?

Thanks so much for your time.

```js
function random_function() {
    var year = document.getElementById("Year");
    var year1 = year.options[year.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("showyear").value = year1

    var a = document.getElementById("Make").value;
    if (a === "Chevrolet") {
        var arr = ["Camaro", "Impala", "Colorado", "Corvette", "Spark"];
    }
    else if (a === "Ford") {
        var arr = ["Fiesta", "Escape", "Focus", "Fusion", "Explorer"];
    }
    else if (a === "BMW") {
        var arr = ["M3", "M5", "X6", "128i", "135i"];
    }
    else if (a === "Audi") {
        var arr = ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8"];
    }
    else if (a === "Toyota") {
        var arr = ["Camry", "Corolla", "Yaris", "Prius", "Highlander"];
    }

    var string = "";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        string = string + "<option value=" + arr[i] + ">" + arr[i] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("Model").innerHTML = string;


    var make = document.getElementById("Make");
    var make1 = make.options[make.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("showmake").value = make1;


    var model = document.getElementById("Model");
    var model1 = model.options[model.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("showmodel").value = model1;

    var parts = document.getElementById("Parts");
    var parts1 = parts.options[parts.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("showparts").value = parts1
}
```

Here is the HTML Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "Scripts\getmodel.js">    
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <select id="Year" onchange="random_function()">
            <option> - Select Year - </option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </select>

<br><br>

        <select id="Make" onchange="random_function()">
            <option> - Select Make - </option>
            <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
            <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
        </select>
<br><br>
        <div>
           <select  id="Model"  onchange="random_function()">
               <Option> - Select Model - </Option> 
           </select>
        </div>
<br>
        <select id="Parts"  onchange="random_function()">
            <option> - Select Parts - </option>
            <option value="Steering Wheel">Steering Wheel</option>
            <option value="Engine">Engine</option>
            <option value="Front door">Front door</option>
            <option value="Rear door">Rear door</option>
            <option value="Clutch Plate">Clutch Plate</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>  
        <input type="text" id="showyear"><br><br>  
        <input type="text" id="showmake"> <br><br> 
        <input type="text" id="showmodel"> <br><br> 
        <input type="text" id="showparts"> <br><br> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm - seems to be working for me in your JSFiddle? If I pick year 2019, then make Chevrolet, it automatically picks the first Model (Camaro)... It all prints out fine in the text fields under your drop down menus. Did you fix the issue by any chance?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question; questions should be self contained, so that if your js fiddle dies for any reason(re: link rot), the question won't be useless to future readers.  So include your html/css in the question as well.

Comment: @nibnut no, I haven't changed. By default it selects the first value in drop down. In Chevrolet, can you try changing to Corvette or spark or some other model and you will see the issue.

Comment: @Daedalus will add html code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're remaking your dropdown on every change.

The user starts by selecting a year, and `random_function` runs. The year is updated, `a` is `""` so `arr` never gets assigned and the model dropdown `innerHTML` is set to `""`, but it was already empty to you don't see any change.

Then the user chooses a make. The year is already set, so it basically gets set to itself again, no visible change. The options for the model are added. So far so good!

But then the user chooses a model. The year gets set to itself again. The options for the model are generated again and the `innerHTML` of the model dropdown is overwritten, wiping out the previous selection.

The short answer is that you need to split up your form processing into different functions for each input. That way a change to the model doesn't cause the make to overwrite the model.

Comment: thank you sir. Created separate functions and also there was an additional issue in HTML issue in onchange. Issue is fixed.